# Composition of Borel measurable and Labegsue mesurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

If $f$ is finite and Lebesgue measurable on $R^n$ and $\phi$ is Borel measurable on $R^1$, then $\phi∘f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

For any open set $G,$ we have that $\phi^{-1}(G)$ is borel measurable. Then how we can do next. I think the proof is similar to continuous version, but I stuke here. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

For any open set $G$,
$$
(\phi\circ f)^{-1}(G)=f^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(G)).
$$
Given that $\phi$ is Borel, $\phi^{-1}(G)$ is Borel, and given that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, $f^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(G))$ is measurable, so $\phi\circ f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Why $f^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(G))$ is measuable? I know is ture is that $\phi^{-1}(G)$ is open, how about borel measuable?

Comment: $\phi^{-1}(G)$ is Borel measurable for any open $G$. That is the definition of $\phi$ being a Borel measurable function. It may not be open, but if it is, it is also Borel measurable since the Borel algebra contains all the open sets.  Then by definition of $f$ being Lebesgue measurable, $f^{-1}(Borel \,\, set)$ is Lebesgue measurable.